# How to use Django url template in a Javascript file

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I'm using Django 3.1 and I would like to know how to use Django URL template in a Javascript file. I'm trying to implement AJAX and when I try to open the connection using the following command in a Javascript file (not inside a script tag in an HTML file):

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHTTPRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "{% url 'checkUser' %}?username=" + encodeURIComponent(username.value), true);
```

The template is not parsed. But if I use the Javascript code inside a script tag in an HTML file, it works fine. Is it possible to use the Django templates in a JS file? How?

Answer (score 1):

one simple way is to save all your urls in html into javascript variables and then use this variables from `.js` files.

In html you will have something like this

```
<script language="Javascript">
   var check_user_url = "{% url 'checkUser' %}";
</script>
```

and then in .js files you can use this variables

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHTTPRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", check_user_url + "?username=" + encodeURIComponent(username.value), true);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Andrey Maslov, but this is exactly what I would like to avoid: to have Javascript and HTML in the same file. But, according to your answer, I believe that there is no way for Django to parse a JS file.

Comment: i think there is a way. you can generate `.js` files as other `.html` templates, but that would be bad idea because usually you want your static files to be cached by server

Comment: you are right. It seans that Django designers did not include full support for the AJAX requests. Based on your comments, I see 3 options: (1) include javascript code in the same HTML file, (2) use separated files and do not use named links from urls.py, or (3) use an extra HTML file just to include the Javascript code. I don't know which option is the worst.

Comment: you can use `data-*` options to store all needed  data for your `.js` files without using javascript in `html` templates